# How does `CreateQuery` work with `TableServiceEntity` in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

Previously, I was working with an Azure Storage Table that my program created, added to, queried from, and deleted itself.

Now, I need to work with one that someone else provides. I used the same query logic, but I can't seem to get anything out of the queries.

The columns in the storage table and the members in `MyEntry` class match exactly, except I did not include the PartitionKey and RowKey in `MyEntry` class.

I also double-checked that the database I'm reading from exists in my code. I also viewed it in Server Explorer to verify its contents. However, I wasn't able to verify in my code if I can view the contents because I cannot read from it.

Here is my query code:

```
        TableServiceContext tableServiceContext = tableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
        var query = from g in tableServiceContext.CreateQuery<MyEntry>(tableName)
                    select g;
```

Here is MyEntry:

```
namespace Project_MyEntry
{
    public class MyEntry: TableServiceEntity
    {
        public string Column3 { get; set; }
        public string Column4 { get; set; }
        public string Column5 { get; set; }
        public string Column6 { get; set; }

        public MyEntry()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I used to be able to simply do the query and get all the entries in the database, but now I'm not getting any. Previously, I had a non-empty constructor that I used to put stuff into my table, but now that my code is not allowed to alter the table, I removed it.

Are there requirements for the TableServiceEntity to fulfill in order to work with the query?

What exactly goes on when you specify a class in `CreateQuery`?

**Edit:** I read on Microsoft's documentation for `TableServiceEntity` that the requirement is to implement getters and setters for each column. I've done this but there's still nothing coming out of the queries. =[

Here's the link to the TableServiceEntity [doc](http://dl.windowsazure.com/javadoc/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/table/client/TableServiceEntity.html).

Comment: Anonymous users do not have access to Windows Azure Tables, so I assume you mean the someone that has created the table has also given you Query access to it. Is that correct? If not you may want to see [Controlling Access to Windows Azure Tables with Java](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn246929.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Why don't you use Azure 2.0, which provides TableEntity as opposed to TableServiceEntity. TableEntity is easier to work with when it comes to queries. 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/